# Is Sceneform 1.17.1 open source?

Tags: arcore, sceneform

I see in the Sceneform repo that `as of` Sceneform 1.16 it is open sourced, see: https://github.com/google-ar/sceneform-android-sdk. What I'm not fully sure on is, does that mean 1.17.1 is open sourced as well? Does anyone know?

Answer (score 0):

Sceneform 1.17.1 is identical to 1.15 - see the note in the readME:

> Sceneform SDK
> version 1.17.1  Identical to version 1.15.0

<strike>I think you can assume it is open source also.</strike> As it is identical to 1.15.0 which is closed source, and the source is not provided separately, it is probably safest to assume it is actually closed, even though much/most of the source will actually be available openly in 1.16.

Note that there are some forks now to try to keep a working version of Sceneform alive - this one if possibly the most supported as it is linked back to some core discussion on ARCore:

- https://github.com/ThomasGorisse/sceneform-android-sdk

(The discussion on the ARCore GitHub: https://github.com/google-ar/arcore-android-sdk/issues/1049)

Comment: Thanks for all  the info. I'm hoping to not have to assume it's open source as this is used at a business. 1.17.1 being identical to 1.15 is what worries me. 1.16 is open sourced, but it's unclear at 1.17.1. 

Thanks for the github link. It looks like that repo is based on Sceneform 1.16. So it's still unclear to me if 1.17.1 is open sourced or not.

Comment: @StephenEmery - Yes, I see what you mean and I'll update the answer as I think what I have said may actually be misleading. Is there some part in particular you do or don't want to be open source as this might be easier to check. As an aside, it is hard to build any product without some open source component somewhere in the stack if this is what you are trying to avoid. Similarly, if hard to avoid closed source building on ARCore.

Comment: Since sceneform was archived, we want to use the open source version to implement into our app. We are totally ok with closed source ARCore, but we want to make changes to Sceneform. So we just want to use the latest open sourced version. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @StephenEmery  I think there is only one open sourced version from Google and that's the 1.16 version . but you do need to be aware it is not the same as 1.15 in case you have built on that, in particular it 'Supports glTF instead of SFA and SFB Sceneform formats'. This was more or less immediately archived as you saw, hence the discussion on the thread above and forks like the 1.18 one above, which currently is the same as 1.16 I believe, but hopefully it, or some other one will gain support and will evolve over time.